# Assigning myLAT + myLON to a variable

Tags: react-native, object, variables

my geolocation snack is working fine. I'm trying to insert myLAT and myLON into a circle radius function without success. Surely its not the way to do it.
I'd like to do something like this please:

```
var myLAT = {this.state.latitude}
var myLON = {this.state.longitude}

let RADIUS = geolib.isPointInCircle(
{latitude: myLAT, longitude: myLON},         //I get error if I don't put a fixed number
{latitude: -34.889014, longitude: -56.107207},
1000
);
```

I hope I've been able to explain myself. I want to be as clear as possible but if required I can post the full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
var myLAT = this.state.latitude
var myLON = this.state.longitude
```

You don’t need to put them in `{}`

Alternatively you could do something like this:

```
const { latitude, longitude } = this.state;
let RADIUS = geolib.isPointInCircle(
  { latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude }, 
  1000
);
```

Regardless you should check the values in your state for latitude and longitude and make sure that they are both numbers.

Comment: Allright @Andrew! But if I put that inside the "componentDidMount() ....=>  " I get no errors, but I cannot use it later in "render (){return...", I mean it's not recognized.
And if I put it outside (it´s recognized in render) but I cannot use the var solution 'cause it gives me errors. Does this make sense to you?

Comment: You could either save the radius in state or make it a global variable.

Comment: Sorry @Andrew, I'm googling it but I don't know how to do that. I can put above the code I'm using if it´s of any use...

Comment: I would suggest posting a new question. That way this question is left untouched so if people have similar issues they can easily see the solution.